# Lower bounding $1/\sqrt{x+y}$ in terms of $1/\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x > y > 0$. I'm looking for a lower bound on $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}$ of the form

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - f(x, y) $$

for some function $f$, which ideally only depends on $y$. I first tried to show that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{y}  $$

but I didn't get anywhere (not sure whether the statement is true).

Are there any known inequalities like this? I'm looking for an as tight as possible inequality.

Comment: If you want $f(y) \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}$, simply find upper bound of $g(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}$ on $x  \ge y$. Since $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(y, \infty)$, we have $g(x) \le g(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt y} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2y}}$. Thus, $f(y) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt y} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2y}}$ is a choice. By the way, you may do it without calculus (by manipulating $g(x)$).